# Copy a MySQL Table into an Array or Collection in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to know how can I possibly copy a table with multiple columns and rows into an Array or Collection in VB.NET.

I want to know the best solution because I want to use the code for 2 different tables and do some comparisons, and the second table has too many records.

I was wondering if in VB.NET there is something similar to Hashmap used in java and a table could look like the following

```
{(Mon, 8, 12); (Tue, 8, 9); etc...}
```

Also after putting the value in an array or whatever collection, how can I possibly re insert these values in a table called "x"?

Comment: Are you using the .NET Framework 4?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download a [MySQL connector for .NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) from the MySQL homepage. Then add a reference to `MySQL.Data.dll`. You also need a reference to `System.data.dll`, however this reference is set by default in new VB projects.

Import the MySQL connector's namespace

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Access the records like this

```
Dim connStr As String = "server=myserver;user id=user;password=secret;database=mydb"
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM mytable", conn)
        conn.Open()
        Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

---

You can insert records like this

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO mytable (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?fn, ?ln)"
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?fn", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = "John"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?ln", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = "Doe"
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Updating records works alike using an update statement

```
UPDATE mytable SET LastName = "Meyers" WHERE id = 55
```

---

The VB `List(Of T)` corresponds to the java `ArrayList<E>`.

The VB `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` corresponds to the java `HashMap<K,V>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated. I was wondering if you could help me finding a solution to my problem. I have a student schedule table with the following record (scheduled, workdate, timein, time out) and I have another table park with the records (spotid, workdate, timein, timeout). I want to write a function that could query workdate, timein, timeout from the first table and check if they exists in the second table for a given spot, if it doesnt exists, a new will be allocated for a random spot, with the workdate, timein and timeout of the first table.

Comment: If the record exists for some number of spot, it will create a new record for a different random spot. The number of spots is fixed to 30. When a schedule from the first table is retrieved for a given student, it will have many rows. The function should iterate over the queried schedule.